# svnedge: how to Discover Multiple "Repository Directory" locations and Authz files

Tags: svn, subversion-edge, authz

I am implementing **SVNEdge** from collabnet in my organization. 
Currently, I have 80+ repositories scattered across 4 different locations on linux server.

1. SVNEdge provides a field, named "Repository Directory:", to mention parent-location where all repositories are kept. **How Multiple parent locations for SVN repositories can be specified to get them discovered in SVNEdge?**
2. Currently every SVN repository has its own Authz file to manage user/group permission. **How can all these authz files be ported to SVNEdge?**

Let me know if more info is required. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that what you are asking is currently possible. So, do some consolidation - manually setup the authorization by merging the authz files with the one used by SVNEdge, then move the repositories to a parent directory and have SVNEdge discover them

Comment: hmm.. so this is what i also thought, authz files needs to be handled manually :( .

Comment: What about the Que-1, can SVNEdge discover Multiple parent directories containing SVN repositories??

Comment: @SameerSingh I have already tried and didn't see any option to do it. Seems like very less people has tried this.

Answer (score 1):

> How Multiple parent locations for SVN repositories can be specified to
>   get them discovered in SVNEdge?

Discover repositories option can find the new repositories only when you have the new repos placed in its default location `csvn/data/repositories`. So, I suggest you to move all your scattered repos into this location and then click Discover Repositories. You can also move everything in a shared folder and specify the new path in the Edge console settings.

> How can all these authz files be ported to SVNEdge?

The access rules can be modified/added in the web UI under the
Access Rules option on the Repositories tab.